# Complex equation solving for a special case

Tags: complex-numbers, systems-of-equations

I have two complex equations(better to say one).

$$a \times d^* = e^{i k}$$
$$d \times a^* = e^{-i k}$$

where $a^*$ is complex conjugate of $a$.

My attempt:
$x_{1}x_{2}+y_{1}y_{2} = \cos(k)$
$y_{1}x_{2}-x_{1}y_{2} = \sin(k)$
where $a = x_{1} + i y_{1}$ and $d = x_{2} + i y_{2}$

Can this be solved, may not be uniquely?
I am sorry for the naive question, but has already spent lot of time with no avail.

Comment: I guess $\;a^*=\overline a=$ the complex conjugate?

Comment: If the above comment's guessing is true, then you have one single equation and then there are infinite solutions...

Comment: @DonAntonio I have edited my ques. How to get atleast one of that infinite solution? Thanks

Comment: Complex arithmetic is like real arithmetic except you don't have an order $<$ that relates to it. In reals if you had $ad=c$ with $c\ne 0$ then  any $(a,d)=(a,c/a)$ is a solution to  $ad=c$ for any $a\ne 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have:
$$
a \cdot \bar d=e^{ik} \; \iff \; a \cdot \bar d \cdot d=e^{ik}\cdot d \; \iff \; a|d|^2=e^{ik}\cdot d \; \iff \;a=\frac{e^{ik}\cdot d }{|d|^2}
$$

The two equations are the same and you can
solve for $d$ the second equation  in the same way.

Comment: A good help surely

Comment: If you don't know $d$ this is all you can do.

Comment: @dxiv : Yes. Thank you.  My stupid typo. I edit.